# Cannot get to CentOS/Apache2 (VirtualBox) website after changing listening port

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, port

I have a webserver built via virtualbox that I had running fine with Port 80. I am currently trying to change the port # to 8088 so that our IT people can open it to the outside world to allow external connections. I have edited my httpd.conf and changed the listen directive as well as added a virtualhost entry for *:8088. I have also added the port into selinux. However, I am still unable to connect to the site by going `http://IP:8088`, it times out saying it could not connect. I have checked netstat and it *appears* that apache is listening to it:

tcp    0      0 :::8088       :::*       LISTEN      6431/httpd

Any ideas what else could be wrong?

Comment: What's the firewall settings?  `iptables -L -n`

Comment: 'Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source  destination

ACCEPT all  --  0.0.0.0/0   0.0.0.0/0    state RELATED,ESTABLISHED

ACCEPT icmp --  0.0.0.0/0   0.0.0.0/0

ACCEPT all  --  0.0.0.0/0   0.0.0.0/0

ACCEPT tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0   0.0.0.0/0    state NEW tcp dpt:22

ACCEPT tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0   0.0.0.0/0    state NEW tcp dpt:80

REJECT all  --  0.0.0.0/0   0.0.0.0/0    reject-with icmp-host-
prohibited'

I am not sure how to get the formatting right here. It keeps squishing all of it together...

Comment: Blah, that's hard to read.  Please edit your Question and add in the iptables output.  A quick glance, though, suggests that you're blocking everything except for SSH (port 22) and HTTP (port 80), so you will need to allow port 8088.

Comment: Yeah sorry. I tried everything I could think of to edit it on here. Apparently they don't allow line breaks. If it would help I could link to a sample txt file or something. I can tell you that currently there is nothing in the OUTPUT section.

Comment: Just wanted to write back that I went ahead and added the port number as an INPUT in my iptables file and things now seem to be working. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: For future reference, you should put those in "code" tags; however, that only works on the original question, not in comments.  Happy ServerFaulting!

Comment: Thanks! I did try that but messed it up somehow lol. I will make sure I do in the future.

Comment: @DewaynePinion I'm going to write up an Answer.  Please accept it so we can clear this Question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From comments, the firewall is:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT) target prot opt source destination
ACCEPT all -- 0.0.0.0/0 0.0.0.0/0 state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT icmp -- 0.0.0.0/0 0.0.0.0/0
ACCEPT all -- 0.0.0.0/0 0.0.0.0/0
ACCEPT tcp -- 0.0.0.0/0 0.0.0.0/0 state NEW tcp dpt:22
ACCEPT tcp -- 0.0.0.0/0 0.0.0.0/0 state NEW tcp dpt:80
REJECT all -- 0.0.0.0/0 0.0.0.0/0 reject-with icmp-host- prohibited
```

So, the INPUT chain for the firewall is only accepting SSH and HTTP (tcp/22 and tcp/80).  You will need to add a firewall rule to accept port tcp/8088.

The best way to do this depends a little on the distribution level you're using, but on CentOS, you can edit `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` and add in the correct line, presumably by copying the one that allows HTTP.